# Intuitive explantion: What is a Finsler metric?

Tags: concept-motivation, geometry, intuition

Neither of the two most evident sources,

- MathWorld: "[Finsler
  Metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FinslerMetric.html)."
- Wikipedia: "[Finsler
  Manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold)."

seems to provide me with the high-level intuition that I could convey
to students in ~10 minutes. And that is because I myself am not 
sufficently schooled in
Finsler geometry.

Either a pointer to a better source, our your own take, would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you would enjoy http://www.ams.org/notices/199609/chern.pdf

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Perfect, Steven---Thanks!

Comment: So, is the answer simply the title of the linked article. I think that comes in at about 10 seconds, well short of the 10 minute mark.

Comment: Why do you want to teach either students or yourself about Finsler metrics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest examples of Finsler metrics are manifolds where the length of a curve is defined by

$$\int \sqrt[\large{4}]{\dot{x}^4 + \dot{y}^4} dt.$$

Distances are then defined by the corresponding infimum.  With this in mind the definitions are easier.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, this is extremely helpful to have such a clear example! I wanted to contrast Riemannian metrics which are locally Euclidean with Finsler metrics which are not (necessarily). And to discuss geodesics on Finsler metrics.